# \LR for long text

Tags: beamer, babel, right-to-left

How can I use Left to Right command, \LR, for long text in a right to left document. It should exist some think like \begin{something} \end{something} but I cannot found it! My problem is in the bibliography section that use Eng.

```
\documentclass[ucs]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Marburg}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\setbeamerfont*{frametitle}{size=\normalsize,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage[persian, english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Script=Arabic,Numbers=Arabic]{XB Zar}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Numbers=Arabic]{XB Zar}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{persian}
\input{translator-basic-dictionary-Persian.dict}
\input{translator-bibliography-dictionary-Persian.dict}
\input{translator-environment-dictionary-Persian.dict}
\input{translator-months-dictionary-Persian.dict}
\input{translator-numbers-dictionary-Persian.dict}
\input{translator-theorem-dictionary-Persian.dict}

\begin{frame}{نمایه}
  \tableofcontents

\end{frame}

\section{مقدمه}

\appendix
\section<presentation>*{\appendixname}
\subsection<presentation>*{منابع}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle<presentation>{For Further Reading}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\selectlanguage{english}

\beamertemplatearticlebibitems

\bibitem{MR94561}
Author1, Author2.
\newblock Title of article.
\newblock {\em Math. Systems Theory}, 29(3):271--291, 2001.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. For example, it may well matter if you are actually using `beamer` as your tags suggest and, if so, which modes you are concerned with. Also, is switching language not the solution here?

Comment: I think that it's easy for experts here to give me a equalent command for \LR for long a text. And No! I changed lang but the Eng letters still print in reverse order! I solved that by \LR to each block of text but is there any simpler solution?!

Comment: That is hardly minimal but thanks for providing some code. Are you using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX? Does that code rely on files people won't have? I'm afraid that I cannot compile it without errors. The first is that `babel` fails to recognise `persian`. If I ignore that, I get complaints about the font selection from `fontspec`.

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer! The solution is \SetLR. Using it after \selectlanguage{english} works for me!

Comment: Perhaps you should post an answer to your question, in that case! By the way, have you looked at `polyglossia`? It doesn't support the main non-English language I use but it seems to be preferred for Arabic.

Comment: I have problem using polyglossia with beamer for persian. It seems I am not allowed to A my Q.

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry. That rings a vague bell. You should be able to answer your question but there may be a time lag before you are allowed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is `\setLR`. Using it after `\selectlanguage{english}` solves the problem.

Comment: This is rather a comment than a qualified solution